# rewrite based on dynamic url htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have sites set up as production or dev. in production mode, visiting example.com will allow all dynamic page rewrites to work, in dev, visiting the ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/~sitename will also allow rewrites of dynamic pages using the htaccess code below:

```
# RewriteBase equivalent - Production
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]

# RewriteBase equivalent - Development
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xx\.xx\.xx\.xx$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/~countryr/]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/-]+)/?$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}page.php?pid=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}blog-detail.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

but I dont always know what will come after /~ for the username, in this code example, the username is countryr, so I can tell htaccess to rewrite to /~countryr and it works, but is there a way to pass this dynamically? so if its /~mysite or /~site2 it will still work? I dont want to have to write the username in all the sites htaccess files.. it a lot of websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture username dynamically using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^64\.6\.104\.14$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/~[^/]+)
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:%1/]
```

Comment: This worked, although.. I had to switch your first rule with the second. the REQUEST_URI must come after the HTTP_HOST. Thanks!

Comment: Oh that's right, since I couldn't test with that IP address condition I just pasted it from question and messed up the order.